# Lower Bound on Distance Between $n $-th and $n+k $-th Prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_n $ represent the $n $-th prime. Say we fix some $n\ge 2$ and some $k\ge 10$. What are some lower bounds on the value
$$p_{n+k}-p_n$$
I am trying to get the largest lower bound that I can. Of course we're probably not going to "discover" these lower bounds on this thread, that's why I'm more so hoping for someone to reference known information.
Currently the best lower bound I have is
$$\frac {5}{2}k$$
Because primes can at most occur at a rate of $2$ every $5$ consecutive integers, any higher rate would imply consecutive twin primes. I also know that primes greater than $x $ tend to occur at a rate of about $\ln(x) $, so would it be possible to get a lower bound that looks something like $k\ln (p_n) $?

Comment: Assuming some common hypothesis (generalizations of twin prime conjecture) the best lower bound can be expressed just in terms of $k$. [Apparently](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes#Current_records) (see conditional section of the table) the best lower bound is conjectured to be asymptotically $k\log k$. I think that this being a lower bound can be proven unconditionally, but being optimal is wide open even for $k=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing  optimistic is provable. At this point, people suspect, only suspect, that there are infinitely many occurrences of any prime constellation. For example, 101, 103, 107, 109 are prime. there are bigger ones. It is suspected that, infinitely often, 10N + 1, 10N + 3, 10 N + 7, 10N + 9 are prime. This means that the lower bound for $p_{k+3}$ is 8.

Get a table of primes and find a constellation of that type, many primes close together. Assume that such a constellation is repeated infinitely often.

Let's see, the quartet above means 10N + 5 is also divisible by 3. Throw in the 7, we have constellation $10n-3, 10n+1,10n+3, 10n+7,10n+ 9, 10n+13,$ centered around $10n + 5.$